# capturing events in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to capture the clicked checkbox and execute an event.

```
var TestApp = React.createClass({
     handleChange: function(){
          var handle = this.getDOMNodes(); //gets entire Div. I want just the selected checkbox
     },
     getInitialState: function(){
         selected: ''
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
               <input type="checkbox" className="option1" onChange={this.handleChange}/> Option1<br />
               <input type="checkbox" className="option2" onChange={this.handleChange}/>Option2<br />
               <span>{this.props.selected}</span>
          </div>
       );
    }
});

React.render(<TestApp />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the event object as you normally would:

```
handleChange: function(event){
  // event.target refers to the DOM element the event originated from
},
```